# SQL Is this shorthand the same? SQL Readability

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple line that looks something like this

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN Unit_MarkDown <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (Partition BY Company_Code, Division_Code, Control_Number, Customer_Purchase_Order_Number) / 
NULLIF(MAX (AMT.Odet_Line_Number) OVER (PARTITION BY AMT.Company_Code,AMT.Division_Code, AMT.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number),0) AS OrderMarkdownedLinesPercent
```

Is this the same as writing

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN Unit_MarkDown <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(MAX (AMT.Odet_Line_Number),0) OVER (Partition BY Company_Code, Division_Code, Control_Number, Customer_Purchase_Order_Number)  AS OrderMarkdownedLinesPercent
```

?

What is the best way to format this line for readability?

Comment: You tell us! Does it return the same results?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  You have two questions.  The first is whether the two versions of code you presented are equivalent.  This is easily testable and so I will leave this to you to answer for yourself.

But the second, regarding readability, I can offer the following alternative format:

```
select      *, 

            OrderMarkdownedLinesPercent = 
                sum(ap.hasMarkdown) over (partition by ap.combined) 
                / max(nullif(odet_line_number,0)) over (partition by ap.combined)

from        someTable
cross apply (select 

                combined = 
                    company_code + '.' + 
                    division_code + '.' + 
                    control_number + '.' + 
                    customer_Purchase_Order_Number,

                hasMarkdown = iif(Unit_MarkDown <> 0, 1, 0)

            ) ap
```

It has the following benefits:

- Code is verticalized.  It is far easier for a coder to have to scroll vertically than horizontally when looking at code overflow.
- Use of cross apply allows the two-step logic for Unit_Markdown to more visibly be split between the validation logic inside the cross apply, and the aggregation logic outside of it.
- Use of cross apply to calculate `combined` gets rid of some redundancy in the partition clause.  This may be less performant.  But test it and if it's not by much, then it's worth the improvement in readability.
- Use of `iif` is not always more readable than `case`, but I put it in just to show it, assuming it's available in your version.
- Using `=` Sql Server allows you to name a column first, then describe its calculation.  I find this very advantageous in terms of readability and it's too bad that not all dialects have it.
- Sometimes I find it more readable to place a binary operator at the beginning of a new line than at the end.  Sometimes I don't.  You see both styles here.
- I might be mistaken, but it should be equivalent to put your `nullif` function inside the `max` function.  If so, I think it looks more readable inside because you keep all open parentheses closer to their close parentheses.

I'm not saying any of these are better or worse.  That is a matter of opinion.  But these are common tools to use when readability is an issue.